# My Rendering view does not look correct. and is showing purple wired shape

Tags: modeling, rendering, uv

I am new in Blender. My Rendering view does not look correct.

[image]

Render view It is showing a purple-wired shape. How do I fix that?

Comment: Pink means missing texture, but it also looks like you've give a Displacement node?

Comment: Looks like you applied displacement modifier and a texture missing

Comment: @moonboots Yes, I have added a Displacement Node. What should I do now? Disconnect this?

Comment: If you don't need displacement, unplug it. If you need displacement, decrease its value, maybe also give a Subdivision Surface to your object so that it has more topology to displace. As for the pink color, you need to find the missing image

Comment: @moonboots wow! now I fixed that, Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need displacement, unplug it. If you need displacement, decrease its value, maybe also give a *Subdivision Surface* to your object so that it has more topology to displace. As for the pink color, you need to find the missing image.